# Syntax changes in Swift 3 with Xcode 8

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift3, xcode8, anyobject

Recently, I convert to **swift 3** and many errors were occurring. 
 Now I convert each lines of codes to swift 3.  :( 
I would like to know how to write loop in swift 3? 
Here it is ...

```
for index in 0...((data as AnyObject).count)!-1{
            print("Hello Everyone")}
```

Could not print the message. May be the syntax of loop in swift 3 changed. 

 Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure about `(data as AnyObject).count`?

Comment: Most probably the problem is not with the for-loop, but with your expression `((data as AnyObject).count)!-1`.  – Start with simpler expressions to isolate the problem! What is `data`? Why cast to `AnyObject`? Why the forced unwrap `!` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you can try the Xcode's Swift migration assistance, that will help reduce your effort & time to convert the code to swift 3 :

When you open your project with Xcode 8.0 for the first time, you will be prompted via the migration assistant to do a migration pass. The assistant can also be invoked manually from the menu Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax…

Also, the problem seems to be in your expression, try following :

```
for index in 0...((data as! [AnyObject]).count-1){ // will work if "data" is non-nil and is an array
        print("Hello Everyone")}
```

Comment: I convert like that. But most lines of codes were not changed automatically. We need to change by ourselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I can print the message now!!!  Swift 3 makes me crazy now. I have to convert the whole app. :(  
Thank you very much for helping me bro.

Comment: Hello bro @Tushar, can I ask one more question please? I would like to know this --> let targetLang = prefs.object(forKey: "selectedLanguage") as? String  and -->  let upper_dashboard_ios: NSArray = prefs.value(forKey: "upper_dashboard_ios")! as! NSArray .  I think it needs to change swift 3?

Comment: @MayPhyu, I think the 2nd part at least needs to be changed to :
let upper_dashboard_ios = prefs.value(forKey: "upper_dashboard_ios") as? NSArray
if let valid_upper_dash = upper_dashboard_ios { // do your work }
Just to let you know, it's not a good practice to place different question in the same thread in stackoverflow, please ask seperately. It also helps in formatting and making right reference in future.

Comment: Yes. I will ask separately next time bro. Thanks for your answers bro @Tushar :)